# unable to display images in a grid using php html

Tags: php, html

Im using the code from this website to display images from a  directory along with their file name.
https://github.com/dcblogdev/gallery-from-folder

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Gallery from Folder Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

-->
</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <?php
        $dirname = "images/";
        $images = scandir($dirname);
        shuffle($images);
        $ignore = Array(".", "..");
        foreach($images as $curimg){
            if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
                echo "<li><a href='".$dirname.$curimg."'><img src='img.php?src=".$dirname.$curimg."&w=300&zc=1' alt='' /></a></li>\n";
            }
        }                 
    ?>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Im getting this funny error in console : -

```
<a href=".$dirname .$curimg."><img src=".$dirname .$curimg."></a>
```

Image isnt showing up (I can only see a broken image icon), when I click on it I see this `http://192.168.1.7/temp/.$dirname%20.$curimg.`

Comment: you just copy it ? are you sure you didn't edit it for error?

Comment: replace you \n to <br>

Comment: "<li><a href=" . $dirname . $curimg . "><img src='img.php?src=" . $dirname . $curimg . "&w=300&zc=1' alt='' /></a></li><br>";

Comment: Looks like the php tag is closed before `\n`. Show us the source code that you have.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, did that . Now Im getting this text  "; } } ?>

Comment: @mPareek Added the html code. Please have a look

Comment: @MdMobinurRahman tried your code , still getting this text on page "; } } ?>

Comment: Tried your code and it works perfectly for me. you may need to do some debugging at your end to find the issue. Start by dumping `$images` array.

Comment: @mPareek typed $images got this-->   Uncaught ReferenceError: $images is not defined

Comment: just replace you \n to <br>

Comment: Where exactly you dumped `$images` ? Looks like you dumped it before it was defined.

Comment: @mPareek on the console of google chrome

Comment: In your php script, do: `var_dump($images);` @SunainaChopra

Comment: @mPareek I did that, but cant see any output on console. Its the same as it was before.

Comment: @SunainaChopra I think you are getting it wrong here. PHP is server side scripting. You can't see its output on browser console(unless used as ajax request). Instead it should print the array on browser window itself. Does your server support the PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

try out this,  here I just simplified the echo of `li` code, and you no need  `\n` at the end of the list tag, coz as per HTML  `li` after completion of one `li` tag it moves to the next line by default

```
<ul>
<?php
    $dirname = "images/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    shuffle($images);
    $ignore = array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$dirname.$curimg.'"><img src="'.$dirname.$curimg.'"></a></li>';
        }
    }               
?>
</ul>
```

here is the working Image

[image]

Comment: Im getting this funny error in console : -   <a href=".$dirname .$curimg."><img src=".$dirname .$curimg."></a>     Image isnt showing up (I can only see a broken image icon), when I click on it I see this http://192.168.1.7/temp/.$dirname%20.$curimg.